# In jhipster generated microservices, application properties defined in central-config is not working

Tags: docker, jhipster, spring-cloud-config, jhipster-registry

I have few microservices(uaa, gateway) generated using jhipster. I am using docker-compose to deploy all microservices. It all worked fine if I keep the database related configurations in uaa-dev.yml inside config folder of uaa-service. However, I wanted to externalize these configuration to a filesystem which is through central-server-config located inside docker-compose folder. Please note I am using JHipster Registry with "dev" and "native" profile which means it should pick up from filesystem.
Additionally, I have created uaa-dev.yml inside central-server-config folder and override DB Configuration.
Another observation is that I am able to change the log level through central-config which means uaa-dev.yml is loaded properly.

### central-server-config/uaa-dev.yml has below configuration

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: DEBUG
    io.github.jhipster: DEBUG
    com.diatoz.uaa: DEBUG

spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myuaa
    username: myuaa
    password: myuaa
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
```

### docker logs for uaa microservice shows below error

```
The application will start in 30s...
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512m -Xms256m

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 2.2.7.RELEASE ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::

2020-08-23 17:25:39.151 DEBUG 1 --- [  restartedMain] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@7237f5da6 pairs: {GET /config/uaa/dev/master HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/vnd.spring-cloud.config-server.v2+json}{Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46ZGlhdG96aXNiZXN0}{User-Agent: Java/11.0.8}{Host: jhipster-registry:8761}{Connection: keep-alive}
2020-08-23 17:25:39.363 DEBUG 1 --- [  restartedMain] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@60b9d98513 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK}{Expires: 0}{Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate}{X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block}{Pragma: no-cache}{Date: Sun, 23 Aug 2020 17:25:39 GMT}{Connection: keep-alive}{Vary: Origin}{Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method}{Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers}{X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}{Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-cloud.config-server.v2+json}
2020-08-23 17:25:39.553  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.diatoz.uaa.UaaApp                    : The following profiles are active: dev,swagger
2020-08-23 17:25:42.172  WARN 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2020-08-23 17:25:44.013 DEBUG 1 --- [  restartedMain] i.m.c.u.i.logging.InternalLoggerFactory  : Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
2020-08-23 17:25:44.780 DEBUG 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.diatoz.uaa.config.WebConfigurer      : Registering CORS filter
2020-08-23 17:25:44.823  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.diatoz.uaa.config.WebConfigurer      : Web application configuration, using profiles: dev
2020-08-23 17:25:44.842  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.diatoz.uaa.config.WebConfigurer      : Web application fully configured
2020-08-23 17:25:44.924 DEBUG 1 --- [  restartedMain] c.diatoz.uaa.config.AsyncConfiguration   : Creating Async Task Executor
2020-08-23 17:25:44.955 DEBUG 1 --- [  restartedMain] c.d.uaa.config.LiquibaseConfiguration    : Configuring Liquibase
2020-08-23 17:25:46.000 ERROR 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:459)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at com.diatoz.uaa.UaaApp.main(UaaApp.java:63)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

2020-08-23 17:25:47.576  WARN 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/app/libs/spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-08-23 17:25:50.432 DEBUG 1 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerAutoConfiguration  : Starting Swagger
2020-08-23 17:25:50.438 DEBUG 1 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerAutoConfiguration  : Started Swagger in 5 ms
2020-08-23 17:25:50.861  WARN 1 --- [  restartedMain] ockingLoadBalancerClientRibbonWarnLogger : You already have RibbonLoadBalancerClient on your classpath. It will be used by default. As Spring Cloud Ribbon is in maintenance mode. We recommend switching to BlockingLoadBalancerClient instead. In order to use it, set the value of `spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled` to `false` or remove spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon from your project.
2020-08-23 17:25:51.048  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2020-08-23 17:25:51.159  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2020-08-23 17:25:51.159  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2020-08-23 17:25:51.251  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2020-08-23 17:25:51.251  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2020-08-23 17:25:51.416  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2020-08-23 17:25:51.430  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2020-08-23 17:25:51.430  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2020-08-23 17:25:51.430  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2020-08-23 17:25:51.430  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2020-08-23 17:25:51.430  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2020-08-23 17:25:51.431  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2020-08-23 17:25:51.431  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2020-08-23 17:25:51.571  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2020-08-23 17:25:51.573  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 5
2020-08-23 17:25:51.575  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 12
2020-08-23 17:25:51.580  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1598203551579 with initial instances count: 0
2020-08-23 17:25:51.585  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1598203551585, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2020-08-23 17:25:51.586  WARN 1 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : Ignoring onDemand update due to rate limiter
2020-08-23 17:25:51.593 DEBUG 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@16d99e7a6 pairs: {GET /config/uaa/dev/master HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/vnd.spring-cloud.config-server.v2+json}{Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46ZGlhdG96aXNiZXN0}{User-Agent: Java/11.0.8}{Host: jhipster-registry:8761}{Connection: keep-alive}
2020-08-23 17:25:51.791 DEBUG 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@4ece721d13 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK}{Expires: 0}{Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate}{X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block}{Pragma: no-cache}{Date: Sun, 23 Aug 2020 17:25:51 GMT}{Connection: keep-alive}{Vary: Origin}{Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method}{Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers}{X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}{Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-cloud.config-server.v2+json}
2020-08-23 17:25:52.076  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.diatoz.uaa.UaaApp                    : Started UaaApp in 15.529 seconds (JVM running for 16.562)
2020-08-23 17:25:52.084  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.diatoz.uaa.UaaApp                    : 
----------------------------------------------------------
        Application 'uaa' is running! Access URLs:
        Local:          http://localhost:9999/
        External:       http://192.168.112.5:9999/
        Profile(s):     [dev, swagger]
----------------------------------------------------------
2020-08-23 17:25:52.085  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.diatoz.uaa.UaaApp                    : 
----------------------------------------------------------
        Config Server:  Connected to the JHipster Registry running in Docker
----------------------------------------------------------
2020-08-23 17:25:52.799 ERROR 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Exception during pool initialization.


2020-08-23 17:25:52.801  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] o.s.b.a.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator   : DataSource health check failed

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:102)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:195)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getHealthStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:176)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:170)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshInstanceInfo(DiscoveryClient.java:1419)
        at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:117)
        at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:101)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:459)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
        ... 24 common frames omitted

2020-08-23 17:25:52.806  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1598203552806, current=DOWN, previous=UP]
2020-08-23 17:25:52.806  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : Ignoring onDemand update due to rate limiter
2020-08-23 17:25:52.806  INFO 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_UAA/uaa:b4a348dfc9391d946e3420a9189d1a2b: registering service...
2020-08-23 17:25:52.897  INFO 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_UAA/uaa:b4a348dfc9391d946e3420a9189d1a2b - registration status: 204
2020-08-23 17:25:53.899 ERROR 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Exception during pool initialization.
```

### Eureka Spring Cloud Config (config/uaa/dev/master)

```
{
  "name" : "uaa",
  "profiles" : [ "dev" ],
  "label" : "master",
  "version" : null,
  "state" : null,
  "propertySources" : [ {
    "name" : "file:central-config/uaa-dev.yml",
    "source" : {
      "logging.level.ROOT" : "DEBUG",
      "logging.level.io.github.jhipster" : "DEBUG",
      "logging.level.com.diatoz.uaa" : "DEBUG",
      "spring.datasource.type" : "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource",
      "spring.datasource.url" : "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myuaa",
      "spring.datasource.username" : "myuaa",
      "spring.datasource.password" : "myuaa",
      "spring.datasource.hikari.poolName" : "Hikari",
      "spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit" : false
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "file:central-config/uaa.yml",
    "source" : {
      "logging.level.ROOT" : "DEBUG",
      "logging.level.io.github.jhipster" : "DEBUG",
      "logging.level.com.diatoz.uaa" : "DEBUG",
      "spring.profiles.active" : "dev",
      "spring.datasource.password" : "uaa"
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "file:central-config/application.yml",
    "source" : {
      "configserver.name" : "Docker JHipster Registry",
      "configserver.status" : "Connected to the JHipster Registry running in Docker",
      "jhipster.security.authentication.jwt.base64-secret" : "ZjBmYTIzNzFmYzQ3OTA3YjY5ZGI5Yjk5NjQ0MmY4NzQ1MjE3YWQ3OWVhODBlZWU1NTMwYzBlNzFmZmFiOWM2ZDgxNTczZGY0NDM1MjQyYWExNTU5MmRjYTc0N2RmNzk0YmU3ZA==",
      "eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone" : "http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka/"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Comment: @GaëlMarziou - Thanks. Yes it is set to dev and config server is connected. I have updated the post with entire log

Comment: Log says 'GET /config/uaa/dev/master', I'm not sure this 'master' part is expected in native backend. Have you tried this URL in the browser or curl to see what your app really gets? and what if you remove the master part?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, thanks again. You mean on registry, right? If I hit http://192.168.0.118:8761/registry/config/uaa/dev it returns error page. BTW 192.168.0.118 is internal IP. Also if I go to registry page I could see profile set to prod. Updated the post. Can this be the reason?

Comment: Yes the registry but you don't need its UI (only the config server API), here the screenshot is for all applications not uaa. The URL from outside docker should be http://admin:admin@localhost:8761l/config/uaa/dev

Comment: Yes. Both config/uaa/dev/master and config/uaa/dev gives same results except label field has master (post updated). Actually if I remove "spring.datasource.url" : "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myuaa", uaa-service starts properly. So should I change any thing in the datasource url?

Comment: While I could not figure out why it is not working though I have followed what is mentioned in the jhipster documentation. However, I have achieved it using docker-compose .env way.